# Default generic type parameter cannot be inferred

Tags: generics, rust, default

I'm trying to implement a Bit Vector library as an exercise, however I'm hitting trouble when wanting to define a default value for a generic type parameter.

This is an excerpt of the code I have:

```
extern crate num;

use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::ops::{BitAnd,BitOrAssign,Index,Shl};
use num::{One,Zero,Unsigned,NumCast};

pub trait BitStorage: Sized + 
    BitAnd<Self, Output = Self> + 
    BitOrAssign<Self> + 
    Shl<Self, Output = Self> + 
    Eq + Zero + One + Unsigned + NumCast + Copy {}

impl<S> BitStorage for S where S: Sized + 
    BitAnd<S, Output = S> + 
    BitOrAssign<S> + 
    Shl<S, Output = S> + 
    Eq + Zero + One + Unsigned + NumCast + Copy {}

pub struct BitVector<S: BitStorage = usize> {
    data: Vec<S>,
    capacity: usize
}

impl<S: BitStorage> BitVector<S> {
    pub fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> BitVector<S> {
        let len = (capacity / (std::mem::size_of::<S>() * 8)) + 1;
        BitVector { data: vec![S::zero(); len], capacity: capacity }
    }

    //...
}
```

And I want to use it as follows:

```
let vec = BitVector::with_capacity(1024);
```

However I get a compiler error:

> lib.rs:225:24: 225:48 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
>   lib.rs:225         let vec_1000 = BitVector::with_capacity(1000);
>                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   lib.rs:225:24: 225:48 help: run `rustc --explain E0282` to see a detailed explanation

To give a little more context to the code, currently valid types for `BitStorage` include (but are not limited to*) `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64` and `usize`.

(*) I think you could write a custom `u128` implementation (just as example) if you implement all the traits for that type.

After googling about the issue I found [RFC 213](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0213-defaulted-type-params.md) which does not seem to [be stable yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27336). However on the other hand [HashMap](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/stable/src/libstd/collections/hash/map.rs) currently on stable is using default values, so it should be working, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support for default type parameters is still limited, but can be used in some cases. When a `struct` with default type parameter is used to specify the type of a variable, the default type parameter is used to define the type of the variable:

```
// the type of vec is BitVector<usize>, so the type of
// BitVector::with_capacity(1024) is correctly inferred
let vec: BitVector = BitVector::with_capacity(1024);
```

> However on the other hand `HashMap` currently on stable is using default values, so it should be working, right?

Looking at the [`HashMap`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.9.0/src/libstd/collections/hash/map.rs#L526-L539) source code, we can see that the methods `new` and `with_capacity` are implemented with `RandomState` for the `S` parameter and does not depend on the default type parameter in `HashMap`. All other methods are implemented as generic on `S`, including other "constructor" methods like `with_hasher`.

You can write something similar:

```
impl BitVector<usize> {
    pub fn default_with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> BitVector<usize> {
        // type is inferred
        Self::with_capacity(capacity)
    }
}

impl<S: BitStorage> BitVector<S> {
    pub fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> BitVector<S> {
        let len = (capacity / (std::mem::size_of::<S>() * 8)) + 1;
        BitVector {
            data: vec![S::zero(); len],
            capacity: capacity,
        }
    }

    // ...
}

// create with "default" BitStore
let vec = BitVector::default_with_capacity(1024);
// specify BitStore
let vec = BitVector::<u32>::with_capacity(1024);
```